# Multiple Instances Of Widget Only Updating Last widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a WidgetProvider and an Configure Activity

When the Widget is started it starts with the configure activity and I set it up by making a custom call to the widgetprovider

(which you will notice is from the sdk tutorial examples)

```
 // Push widget update to surface with newly set prefix
              AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
              AwarenessWidget.updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager,
                      mAppWidgetId, position);

            // Make sure we pass back the original appWidgetId
            Intent resultValue = new Intent();
            resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
            finish();
```

I pass the Widget ID to the function.... inside the widget I create a Intent like this:

```
  Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, Configure.class);
    configIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity
    (context, 0, configIntent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.MainImage,pendingIntent);

    views.setImageViewResource(R.id.MainImage, lv_images[version]);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
```

I am always referencing the widget ID and even add it as a extra on the intent
but when I get two of these widgets on the home screen the widget ID is always referencing the last placed widget ID

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Just add this to your config activity, where you set your PendingIntent:

```
Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(
    Uri.parse(URI_SCHEME + "://widget/id/")
    ,String.valueOf(appWidgetId));
intent.setData(data);
```

The variable URI_SCHEME is a String, and can be whatever you'd like.. ie - "ABCD" This causes each widget to have a unique PendingIntent.

Comment: I don't set a pendingintent in my config activity, only in the widget function that the activity calls

Comment: This works but I don't understand why.  Can someone please explain this answer a bit further?

Comment: @Mike After a bit of research I discovered an explanation of why this answer works. Please see my alternate answer below.

Comment: In my case I had a problem with Collection widget. So when I've added my second widget on the home screen, the RemoteViewFactory didn't call. So I pasted this for the intent, which launches the RemoteViewService. `intent.data = Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME))` Working great.

Answer (score 40):

Here is a more in-depth explanation of why your code doesn't work and how to fix it. From the Android SDK Documentation:

> A PendingIntent itself is simply a reference to a token maintained by
>   the system describing the original data used to retrieve it. This
>   means that, even if its owning application's process is killed, the
>   PendingIntent itself will remain usable from other processes that have
>   been given it. If the creating application later re-retrieves the same
>   kind of PendingIntent (same operation, same Intent action, data,
>   categories, and components, and same flags), it will receive a
>   PendingIntent representing the same token if that is still valid, and
>   can thus call cancel() to remove it.
>
> Because of this behavior, it is important to know when two Intents are
>   considered to be the same for purposes of retrieving a PendingIntent.
>   A common mistake people make is to create multiple PendingIntent
>   objects with Intents that only vary in their "extra" contents,
>   expecting to get a different PendingIntent each time. This does not
>   happen. The parts of the Intent that are used for matching are the
>   same ones defined by Intent.filterEquals. If you use two Intent
>   objects that are equivalent as per Intent.filterEquals, then you will
>   get the same PendingIntent for both of them.

Note that specifying differing "extra" contents isn't enough for the PendingIntents to be considered unique, but setting a unique URI with setData is. That is why Snailer's URI solution "magically" fixes the problem.

The documentation also offers a different (arguably simpler) solution to the problem. Instead of creating a custom URI just set a unique requestCode when you call getActivity:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, appWidgetId, configIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

Comment: requestCode is not currently used by the SDK but it does cause the Intent to be considered unique. The documentation suggests this is a valid use of requestCode: "or different request code integers supplied to getActivity"

Answer (score 13):

In my testing, using the setData(...) on the PendingIntent doesn't fix the issue on a Verizon Thunderbolt running Android 4.0.4. It works on my other test devices and emulator.

I tested the use of the requestCode instead, and it works in all cases. I just set the requestCode to be the widget ID:

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, appWidgetId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```