# Permission Denial: getIntentSender()

Tags: android, android-widget, android-pendingintent

I'm trying to set a pending intent for a widget in the onUpdate method of the app widget provider however I'm constantly getting a Permission Denial: getIntentSender() when trying to set the pending intent. I've stripped the class right down for simplicity:

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    Intent appIntent = new Intent(context,Main.class);
    PendingIntent pendingAppIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context, 0, appIntent, 0);

   super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}
```

I get the following stacktrace for this:

```
06-23 10:18:45.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6536): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to    start receiver com.distilledmedia.thejournal.widget.JournalAppWidgetProvider: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: getIntentSender() from pid=6536, uid=10062,   (need uid=-1) is not allowed to send as package com.distilledmedia.thejournal.client
06-23 10:18:45.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6536):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1805)
06-23 10:18:45.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6536):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-23 10:18:45.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6536):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:981)
06-23 10:18:45.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6536):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-23 10:18:45.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6536):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-23 10:18:45.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6536):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-23 10:18:45.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6536):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 10:18:45.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6536):     at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-23 10:18:45.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6536):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-23 10:18:45.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6536):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-23 10:18:45.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6536):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-23 10:18:45.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6536): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: getIntentSender() from pid=6536, uid=10062, (need uid=-1) is not allowed to send as package com.distilledmedia.thejournal.client
06-23 10:18:45.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6536):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1322)
06-23 10:18:45.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6536):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
06-23 10:18:45.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6536):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getIntentSender(ActivityManagerNative.java:2254)
06-23 10:18:45.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6536):     at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:195)
06-23 10:18:45.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6536):     at com.distilledmedia.thejournal.widget.JournalAppWidgetProvider.onUpdate(JournalAppWidgetProvider.java:41)
06-23 10:18:45.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6536):     at android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider.onReceive(AppWidgetProvider.java:61)
06-23 10:18:45.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6536):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1794)
```

And here's the entry for the App Widget in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="com.distilledmedia.thejournal.widget.JournalAppWidgetProvider" >
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data  android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/journal_widget" />
</receiver>
```

And the entry for the main activity:

```
<activity android:name="com.distilledmedia.thejournal.client.Main"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges="orientation" android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Could it be to do with the the fact that the widget is in a different package to the main activity?

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011178/multiple-instances-of-widget-only-updating-last-widget/4011431#4011431) answered by [snailer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/408178/snailer).