# One Widget Class and multiple widgets with different data

Tags: android, android-widget

I've one appwidget class and I need to create few widgets but each of them must storage other data set in WidgetConfigure. Clicked widget should show activity with this data. I save my data to shared preferences and read it in widget, but if i try add next widget, it override existing data. How can i do that? I was tried something like that

```
configEditor.putInt("a"+mAppWidgetId, a_num); //it's in widgetconfigure class
int a = config.getInt("a"+mAppWidgetId, 0); //widget class
```

I've no idea how to solve it. After update all widget contain the same data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you're right. If you need to store different values for different widget instances you should append id value of the widget to the key. A possible way how to do this is described in the book `Pro Android 3`.

But if you want to store only one integer there is other way to do this. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011178/multiple-instances-of-widget-only-updating-last-widget) for more details.

Comment: Thank you, I have to buy it :) Now I was using Pro Android 2 :P